# Numeric Ranges with a Regular Expression python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, numeric-ranges

So I am working on a text analytics problem and I am trying to remove all the numbers between 0 and 999 with regular expression in Python. I have tried Regex Numeric Range Generator to get the regular expression but I didn't succed. I can only remove all the numbers.

I have tried several Regex but it didn't work. here's what I tried

```
# Remove numbers starting from 0 ==> 999
data_to_clean = re.sub('[^[0-9]{1,3}$]', ' ', data_to_clean)
```

I have tried this also:

```
# Remove numbers starting from 0 ==> 999
data_to_clean = re.sub('\b([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9])\b', ' ', data_to_clean)
```

this one:

```
^([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9])$
```

and this:

```
def clean_data(data_to_clean):
    # Remove numbers starting from 0 ==> 999
    data_to_clean = re.sub('[^[0-9]{1,3}$]', ' ', data_to_clean)  
    return data_to_clean
```

I have a lot of numbers but I need to delete just the ones under 3 decimals and keep the other.

Thank You for your help

Comment: shouldn't this combination from your tries work:  `\b[0-9]{1,3}\b`?
If you check: https://regex101.com/r/qDrobh/6 it should work

Comment: could you post an example text, where the numbers should be replaced?

Comment: **bonjour  la commande 2000501784 est validée  et pour autant  je ne peux la réceptionner  poste 30   merci d avance **   I am getting the same result

Comment: I should delete 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need precede the pattern string with an `r` to prevent escaping so the interpeter won't swap `\b` with a backspace. Plus you can simplify the pattern like this:

```
data_to_clean = re.sub(r'\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2})\b', ' ', data_to_clean)
```

Comment: Not sure if it is required but numbers with leading zero are not included (e.g. 000, 001, ...) I think it was intentional but it's worth to mention

Comment: I assumed leading zeros should not be included since op tried to use a Regex Numeric Range Generator

Comment: I like your answer way more, then JGNI's since a lookahead is really expensive and not necessary here. It also shows his answer needs >400 steps compared to ~200 steps from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a combination of your try with word boundaries (`\b`) and your last try (`[0-9]{1,3}`).

So the resulting regex should look like: `\b[0-9]{1,3}\b`

If you check the demo:  regex101.com/r/qDrobh/6 
It should replace all 1-digit, 2-digit and 3-digit numbers and ignore higher numbers and other words.

Comment: it doesn't remove the numbers even with those regular expressions.

Comment: You are welcome, but dont forget to mark the correct answer and/or vote for helpful comments. The answer from @krisz looks very good to me, and even considers whether leading zeros are there. But it will not remove 000 for example

Comment: Ok @gaw. Thank u for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Numbers from 0 to 999 are

1. A single character [0-9]
2. Two characters [1-9][0-9]
3. Three characters [1-9][0-9][0-9]

This gives a naive  regex of `/\b(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])\b/` However we have duplicated characters classes in the options so we can factor them out

```
/(?!\b0[0-9])\b[0-9]{1,3}\b/
```

This works by using a negative lookahead `(?!\b0[0-9])` to check for the start of a word followed by a 0 followed by a digit to disregard 01 etc. and then looks for 1 to three 0 - 9 characters. Because the negative lookahead needs at least 2 characters a single `0` still passes as valid.

Comment: it doesn't remove the numbers even with those regular expressions